# Eliminar registro de dos arrays

Tags: php

Buenas he estado buscando alguna función en php, que me quite datos que sean iguales de un array y otro ejemplo:

tengo 2 arrays 1 con 3 registros y otro con 30, lo que quiero hacer es que si en esos 3 se repite lo mismo en el segundo array entonces que lo quite, o no me lo muestre y el resultado seria 27 registros del segundo array no se si halla algo parecido que me pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Hola estuve revisando y puede ser de ayuda la función array_diff(), mira [la documentación de php](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). `array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )` compara dos o más array y entrega un array de los valores del primer array que no están en los demás array que pusiste a comparar.

Tambien puede serte útil otra pregunta de StackOverflow [pero en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array) que muestra más funciones para borrar elementos de arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Por aca tienes dos posibles soluciones para remover duplicados dados dos arreglos:

## Opcion 1

```
$arreglo_nuevo = array_unique( array_merge($arreglo_1, $arreglo_1) );
```

## Opcion 2

```
$arr_1 = array_diff($arr_1, $arr_2);
$arr_2 = array_diff($arr_2, $arr_1);
```

y si te da problemas con los indices, es decir que no sigan la secuencia 0,1,2,3,n+1...
utiliza la funciono siguiente y lo tendras como deseas :D

```
array_values($arreglo);
```

## Referencias:

- http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php
- http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php
- http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php